# Possible to include a bootstrap badge on a cytoscape node?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cytoscape.js

Is it possible to incorporate a bootstrap badge on a cytoscape node using a css selector accessing a JSON file in the same way that colours and shapes can be defined?

Comment: tremendous effort to down vote without explanation

Comment: No idea why someone downvoted you, but I've balanced it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `background-image` property in your stylesheet: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/background-image

There are several `background-*` properties to control size, position, etc.  You can even put the image outside the node shape if you set `background-clip: none`.